# Server 2012 intermittently fails to respond to pings from single host, even with firewall disabled, but responds to non-ICMP requests fine

Tags: windows-server-2012, ping

This one is kind of weird. I've got the following machines involved:

DC01 - 10.1.2.42, Server 2012, domain controller & DNS server, physical machine
nagiosv - 10.1.2.35, CentOS 6.4, Nagios, virtual machine
CB01 - 10.1.3.81, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, couchbase server, virtual machine

So, I noticed something was wrong while configuring this new Nagios VM. I started seeing DC01's state flapping. I logged into nagiosv when I saw this happening, and attempted to ping DC01, both by FQDN and its IP address. Neither worked. I tried pinging the machine from CB01, which is another VM on the same virtual switch/physical NIC as nagiosv, and that worked fine. Pings still failing from nagiosv at this time.

DC01 is also an internal DNS server, so I ran **dig google.com** from nagiosv, and was able to run a query against DC01 just fine:

```
;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.1.2.42#53(10.1.2.42)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov  1 07:53:51 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 204
```

Pings still failing from nagiosv, though. I can ping from DC01 *to* nagiosv, and that works, and I can still ping from other VMs on the same physical NIC into DC01, and that works. I should mention at this point that I've disabled the firewall on DC01 for testing purposes, and it doesn't make a damned bit of difference. (Even with the firewall enabled, I have a blanket exception for ICMP from the local subnet, so it shouldn't make a difference, but I figured I should test it anyway.)

I loaded up Wireshark on DC01 and pinged it from nagiosv again. What I see is a bunch of echo requests coming in and not a single reply going back out. [Filtered results here, showing all ICMP traffic during a 15-second period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU4vk.png).

A few more bits of info: There are no IP conflicts on the network. MAC addresses on the incoming pings match the MAC on the VM. There are no duplicate MACs on the network, as far as I can see.

I have absolutely no idea why DC01 is failing to respond, here. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of effort to troubleshoot something that has absolutely no bearing on anything. If the DC is otherwise functioning properly and providing the services to the clients that it is intended to then why do you care if it doesn't respond to pings? Ping is one of the most overused and incorrectly used troubleshooting tools. Also, what do you mean that you noticed the DC "flapping"? What does "flapping" mean in this context?

Comment: Do you control the physical network behind your hypervisor host? This sounds suspiciously like a switch port configured to limit the maximum of mac entries..

Comment: Pauska: I do, but, unfortunately, they're unmanaged switches. That's not a bad theory, though, and I'll look into it.  

Joeqwerty: "Flapping," in Nagios terms, means the host/device's state (according to Nagios) is going up/down too quickly. Ping is used by Nagios, by default, to verify host availability. I guess I could try to figure out a different check to determine host availability.

Comment: Cheap unmanaged switches are something I would avoid, especially in a virtualized environment where you could have a lot of mac address changes. Try reseting the switch and see if a clean address table helps.